# Finding 406 MHz frequency using android or iOS app

Tags: android, ios, gps

Is it possible to write code that finds the frequency of 406 MHz frequency ? I'm trying to build a search and rescue app

Thanks !

Comment: Do you mean like detect an actual RF signal transmitted by some other device (not a phone)? Then no.

Comment: There's no Android devices I know of that has an in-built RF receiver.

Comment: search and resuce apps should be written by people with a sufficient technical knowledge

Answer (score 0):

1) There is an Android device with RF capability. See the Earl outdoor tablet. http://meetearl.com

2) An alternative would be to use a RTL-SDR USB dongle to receive the frequency and use the app to control the dongle. The dongles are about $8-20 via eBay. I'd mount the dongle on a directional antenna so reduce RFI from the Android device. There is an existing iSDR app that controls these dongles.